# Level set of convex functions

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R^n \to\mathbb R \cup\{+\infty\}$ be a proper convex function, assume that there exists $c\in\mathbb R$ such that the $c$-level set $L_{\leq c}=\{x\in R^n: f(x)\leq c\}$ is nonempty and bounded. Prove that all level sets of $f$ are also bounded.

Comment: If $f$ is closed then this is straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need $f$ to be closed (equivalent to lower semi-continuous for a proper function).

Define $f:\mathbb R^2 \to\mathbb R \cup\{+\infty\}$ as follows:
$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
0, & x=0, y=0\\
y, & y >0 \\
+\infty, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

$f$ is proper, convex, $L_{\leq 0} = \{ (0,0) \}$ which is bounded and $ \mathbb{R} \times \{ 1\}  \subset L_{\leq 1} $ which is unbounded.

Now suppose $f$ is closed. In particular, this means the level sets are closed.

I will proceed by contradiction: Suppose $c_1<c_2$ are such that $L_1=L_{\leq c_1}$ is bounded, but $L_2=L_{\leq c_2}$ is not.
(note that $L_1 \subset L_2$.)
Then there is a non-zero $d \in 0^+ L_2$, the recession cone of $L_2$ (for example, see Rockafellar, "Convex Analysis", Theorem 8.4). In particular, if $x_1 \in L_1$, we have $x_1+t d \in L_2$ for all $t \ge 0$. The function $\phi(t) = f(x_1+t d)$ must be nonincreasing (if not, then $x_1+td \notin L_2$ for some $t>0$), in which case
we must have $x_1+t d \in L_1$ for all $t \ge 0$, which contradicts boundedness of $L_1$.

Comment: @ Copper.hat: Where is the assumption $f$ closed used in your proof?

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear; the Theorem quoted above states that a closed convex set if unbounded **iff** its recession cone consists of the zero vector alone. The main use above is to ensure that if $d$ is a direction of recession of $L_2$, then $x_0+td \in L_2$ for all $t \ge 0$ (and all $x_0 \in L_2$). In the 'counterexample' above, you can see that $e_1$ is a direction of recession for $L_{\leq 1}$ (well, more correctly $\operatorname{ri} L_{\leq 1}$), but $(0,0)+ t e_1 \notin L_{\leq 1}$ for any $t$.

Comment: Minor point: I have only shown that closed is sufficient to prove your statement, and provided a non-closed counterexample. It is not necessary for $f$ to be closed for the statement to be true as the example $f(x) = 0$ for $\|x\|<1$ and $+\infty$ otherwise shows.

Comment: Sure, take $C=\mathbb{R}\times (0,1)$.

Comment: No, because $0^+(\operatorname{ri} C) = 0^+(\bar{C})$ if $C$ is non-empty. (And if $C$ is open then $\operatorname{ri} C = C$.)

Comment: Can you show me: is there a nonempty (non closed) unbouded convex set C but $o^+(C)=\{0\}$. Thank you very much!

Comment: Take $C=(\mathbb{R} \times (0,1)) \cup \{ (0,0) \}$. Then the only directions of recession are $\pm e_1$, but it doesn't 'work' at $(0,0)$, so $0^+ C = \{(0,0)\}$. Note that $0^+(\operatorname{ri} C) = 0^+(\bar{C}) = \operatorname{sp} \{ e_1 \}$.

Comment: I feel like I'm playing a convex chess game :-).

Comment: I mean an open horizontal slab with the point $(0,0)$ added in (so it is neither open nor closed). Oh, I see a point of confusion, the first $(0,1)$ means the open interval, the second $(0,0)$ means the origin in 2-space.

Comment: Btw, if you are happy with an answer it is customary to accept it after some period of time.